# Which Google Data YouTube API Client ID to use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access YouTube API using ASP.net MVC 4.

Should I use :

`Client ID for web application` or `Client ID for native application`?

I tried both:

Using Client ID for web application will give me this error: `The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:55193/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI`

Using Client ID for native application will redirect me to this page with a token: `http://localhost:55318/authorize/?code=4/ufFRXOfT7GS28wg_eqA9pQ9wVtFN.cgyV3VCJtGkXdJfo-QBMszsijcV9jQI`

I am confused of google limited documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a WebApp, you should use the client ID for web application. The error messages you're seeing indicate that your app is configured to, after authorizing, redirect to the URLs you see there, but you haven't set, in the console, the permissions to let those URLs handle callbacks.

Visit the developer console (https://console.developers.google.com/) and find your project, then choose the "credentials" link under the APIs & Auth section. Look for the client ID that you're using, and edit it; there will be a field to put in your allowed redirect URIs (in other words, the permissible places that your oAuth calls can redirect to after visiting google's auth endpoints).